# Nice way to truncate an integer

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, rounding, numeric-limits

I have a function which is given a buffer which accepts to be filled up to a `size_t` length; however, the actual call which fills it wants an `int` as max length.

So, in case the parameter cannot fit in an integer, I want it truncated to the maximum value that can fit; as I couldn't get more data anyway.

I can do this

```
int truncatedMaxLen = static_cast<int>(std::min<std::size_t>(maxLength, (std::numeric_limits<int>::max)()));
```

Any less ugly ways?

Comment: Sure.  Make it a function so you have something like `int truncatedMaxLen = truncate_int(maxLength);`.

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. Are you sure losing data is the correct behavior and not maybe telling the user that the program failed to do its job because the data set is too large?

Comment: Just in case, this is called [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic).

Comment: @nwp I am _not_ losing data. I'm just ignoring extra free space, which is marked as available by the upper levels but cannot possibly be used all at once by the lower level. The parameter passed is an upper limit on how many positions are available, not a requirement that I write them all, so failing would be wrong.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin sadly, it seems that proposals to natively support saturation arithmetic never went anywhere.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi Intel CPUs support it natively with SIMD instructions.

Comment: @nwp If you ever saw a rendered 3D picture - shading is built on saturation arithmetic.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin it could be made to work, but as I see it resorting to `__asm` is ugly in its own right. Visual Studio does not even support it when compiling in 64 bit mode.

Comment: You totally do not need `__asm` for that. See https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/, https://locklessinc.com/articles/sat_arithmetic/.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin so according to that link what I could do is `int truncatedMaxLen = maxLength; truncatedMaxlen |= -(truncatedMaxLen < maxLength);`. Ingenious! Rather obscure though.

Comment: @FrancescoDondi That would work for unsigned types, but not for signed.

Answer (score 2):

A branchless way would be:

```
int truncatedMaxLen = maxLength;
truncatedMaxLen |= (truncatedMaxLen < maxLength) * std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

For unsigned types it is nicer because there is no sign bit to take care of:

```
unsigned truncatedMaxLen = maxLength;
truncatedMaxLen |= -(truncatedMaxLen < maxLength);
```